# Making up examples for $S(k,n)n!$ where $S(k, n)$ is a Stirling Number of the Second Kind

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

First Example:

What's the number of seven-letter passwords whose elements are taken out of $\{A, B, C\}?$

Why I think this works:

We can translate the problem above into the question "In how many ways can we distribute seven distinct places to three letters?" Then we'd be dealing with surjective functions from $\{\text{distinct places in a password}\}$ to $\{A, B, C\}$ which by twelvefold way is $S(7, 3)3!$

Second Example:

Suppose $9$ students are about to move to NYC, London, Tokyo and Rio after graduation. In how many ways can that be done?

Why I think this works:

I think we are just distributing $9$ distinct balls into $4$ distinct boxes s.t. each box gets at least one ball. Then the answer by twelvefold way should be $S(9, 4)4!$

Would these questions be acceptable for the given answer $S(k,n)n!$?

Comment: I agree with the second one. The first one is not clear if you have to use all the letters or not. If you have to use them all, you are correct, if not, no.

Comment: @Phicar. Thanks. I will just pretend I meant to say everything in $\{A, B, C\}$  has a pre-image :)

Comment: So you are correct :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S(k,n)n!$ is the number of surjective functions from a set with $k$ elements into a set with $n$ elements.  So anytime you're splitting distinguishable items into distinguishable groups in such a way that no group is empty, that's going to be the solution.